# How to catch the new correct ULR after payment gate redirection in Playwright

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, playwright

I test something on the first page and after filling the form with excepted data there is a payment button with redirection to the second page with completely different url (payment gate Payu).
It goes like this:

```
await page.goto('https:/first-page.com')
```

Some steps with filling data into form

```
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Pay', exact: true }).click();
await page.getByTitle('Payment_option_1').click();
```

With the last instruction there a problem because page url has changed but Playwright seems to does not know about this and it tries to search for 'Payment_option_1' button on the old url version.
It would be easier when I could know the exact url I will redirected to, but the new url is with one-time token different every time.

Is there any solution to assure Playwright that the new url has come and it should seeks for the next element on the new page url, without page.goto('ExactTheNewURL')

playwright.config.ts below:

```
/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
// require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: 'html',
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    // baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
    },

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
    //   use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
    // },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Edge'], channel: 'msedge' },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Google Chrome',
    //   use: { ..devices['Desktop Chrome'], channel: 'chrome' },
    // },
  ],

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  // webServer: {
  //   command: 'npm run start',
  //   url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  //   reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  // },
});
```

Comment: By default, Playwright `.click()` is [supposed to wait for nav](https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#auto-wait-1), so your code should just work. Can you share a [mcve]? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may assert the regex for new URL:

```
 await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Pay', exact: true }).click();
 await page.waitForURL(/.*merch-prod.snd.payu.com/, {timeout:30000});
 await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*merch-prod.snd.payu.com/);
 //Next steps
```

So you don't need to know the exact URL but some part (pattern) of it.

Reference:https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-url

Comment: Redirected url looks like this:
https://merch-prod.snd.payu.com/pay/?orderId=id&token=token#/payment

I've tried with: 
```await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*payment/);```

and from the report I've received an error, where received string is the primary url (not redirected one):
Expected pattern: /.*payment/
Received string:  "https://oldlink/demo.html

```await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Pay', exact: true }).click();```
```await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*payment/);```
```await page.getByTitle('Payment_option_1').click();```

Comment: When I use 'Record new' to generate the code automatically there is a strict instruction with the new page.goto - but I do not know the right url in advance because of the one-time token.

Comment: It may be taking more than default 5 seconds in getting new URL so I added more timeout.Please try with it.

Comment: Also in new URL , there is nothing like 'payment' in the string as you provided.

Comment: I've tried also like this:
```await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*merch-prod.snd.payu.com/, {timeout:30000});```

Real redirected url structure:
https://merch-prod.snd.payu.com/pay/?orderId=id&token=token#/payment

Error: expect(received).toHaveURL(expected)

Expected pattern: /.*merch-prod.snd.payu.com/
Received string:  "https://testing-page.com/SpecializationId=id&telemediSubscriptionEnabled=true" - old url again

Comment: @DarekAdamczyk If it still does not work for you , please share your config and test file code as updated in the answer , not in the comments as then formatting gets lost.

Comment: Here is the error I've received right now:
```Error: page.waitForURL: Navigation failed because page was closed!```
In this line:
```await page.waitForURL(/.*merch-prod.snd.payu.com/, {timeout:30000});```
page has still the same old url. I've checked it through console.log.
Config has been added in the main msg. It is totally default.
Thanks for your effort so far!

Comment: @DarekAdamczyk If page itself is getting closed , verifying URL itself is out of question as then it's totally different issue.

Comment: You have not shared the test script code in question.